# Make unique routes for each object in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a small project management system, and I have tasks, which are part of a project. I know how to list all tasks in a list in the front end, but I want to make an unique route like `/ProjectName/Tasks` for each project.

How can I build this in ASP.NET Core v3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route template with a placeholder ie `"{projectName}/Tasks"`

```
//...

[HttpGet("{projectName}/Tasks")]
public IActionResult GetProjectTasks(string projectName) {

    //...get tasks based on project name

}

//...
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)